# Finding value of infinite series limit

Tags: limits

> Finding value of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2-\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+........+\sqrt{2}}}}}_{\bf{n\; times}}}{4^{-n}}$

Try: I am trying to convert it into $\cos$ ine series sum

Let $$\displaystyle \sqrt{2+2\cos \theta } = 2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}$$ and

$$\displaystyle \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos \theta}} = 2\cos \frac{\theta}{4}$$

$$\displaystyle \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos \theta}}} = 2\cos \frac{\theta}{8}$$

could some help me how i write $$\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+........+\sqrt{2}}}}}_{\bf{n\; times}}$$ into cosine series form. thanks

Comment: I think there might be a typo, as the nested radical converges to $2$ and there isn’t even an indeterminate form.

Comment: well, you almost did it already: the starting point is $\theta =\pi/4$

Comment: The limit of fraction is  $-∞$ because the limit if numerator is $\sqrt 2-2$ when n goes to infinity.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_Formula_for_Pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \underbrace {\sqrt 2 }_1 = 2\cos \left( {\pi /4} \right)  \cr 
  & \underbrace {\sqrt {2 + \sqrt 2 } }_2 = \sqrt {2 + 2\cos \left( {\pi /4} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sqrt {2\left( {1 + \cos \left( {\pi /4} \right)} \right)}  = \sqrt {2\left( {1 + \cos ^2 \left( {\pi /8} \right) - \sin ^2 \left( {\pi /8} \right)} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sqrt {4\cos ^2 \left( {\pi /8} \right)}  = 2\cos \left( {\pi /8} \right)  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \vdots   \cr 
  & \underbrace {\sqrt {2 + \sqrt { \cdots  + \sqrt 2 } } }_n = 2\cos \left( {\pi /2^{n + 1} } \right) \cr} 
$$

Then probably you are looking for the value of $\lim_ {n \to \infty}{(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\cdots}})4^n}$.

Comment: You can also mention the asymptotic $\cos x\sim 1-x^2/2$

Comment: @szeto: you are right, and it is applicable if there is a typo in the expression of which to take the limit and it's leading term is $2$ instead of $\sqrt{2}$